# Adding new calculated columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Assume I have a small data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             ["A",  28, 726, 120],
             ["B",  28, 1746, 250],
             ["C", 543, 15307, 4500]
         ],
         columns = ["case", "x", "y", "z"]
    )
```

I know how to calculate a *total* column as (for example):

```
cols = list(df.columns)
df['total'] = df.loc[:, cols].sum(axis=1)
```

Now I would like to **append** to `df` 3 other columns `x_pct, y_pct, z_pct`, containing the percentage of `x,y,z` in relation to `total`, that is to say: `x_pct=100*(x/total)`, etc.

And after that, I would like to **still append** 3 new columns `x_pctr, y_pctr, z_pctr`, containing the percentages rounded to a whole number: `round(x_pct)`, etc.

Although I know, of course, how to calculate individually `x_pct, x_pctr` and so on, I couldn't find how to express simply the calculation of the 3 "percentage columns" in one run (and besides the calculation of the 3 "rounded columns" in one run), nor to construct a "global" data frame containing the previous columns **and** the resulting ones...

I am a little confused because I guess `apply(lambda...)` would do the job, if only I knew how to use it? Could you get me out of there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df[["x_pctr", "y_pctr", "z_pctr"]] = (
    df.loc[:, "x":].div(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0) * 100
).round()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  case    x      y     z  x_pctr  y_pctr  z_pctr
0    A   28    726   120     3.0    83.0    14.0
1    B   28   1746   250     1.0    86.0    12.0
2    C  543  15307  4500     3.0    75.0    22.0
```